# How to reach something in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying very long but I don't get it.

I have my array:

```
public $cards = array( 
    array('name' => "arya", 'show' => "hidden")
);
```

and want my programm to work with it.

I tried it like this but it didn't work. There is no error message.
I wanted to replace the first one with this new div

```
if (isset($this->cards['name']) == "name") {
    echo "<td><div style='height: 150px, width: 150px;'></div></td>";
}
```

Is my question too vague? :S then I am really sorry. I am not very good at asking specified questions.

Comment: since you're new to stackoverflow: you shouldn't downvote all answers that don't work for you. generally answers are being downvoted when they are going in a complete different direction or are utterly wrong. some of these answers do seem right, according to your question.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything :S Well not knowingly. If I did so then sorry. It was not my opinion

Comment: no biggie, just a wild assumption ;) - saw all the answers get downvoted to oblivion right after you told them they don't work for you.

Comment: @zwacky: Please don't just accuse other people of downvoting based on assumptions. In this case, the OP only has 1 reputation (you need at least 125 to cast a downvote).

Answer (score -2):

(updated)

Try this instead :

```
foreach ($this->cards as $cardArray) {
     if (isset($cardArray['name']) && $cardArray['name'] == "arya") {
        echo "
            <td><div style='height: 150px, width: 150px;'></div></td>
                ";
     }
}
```

You have to separate the first test (`isset`) and the second one (`== "name"`).

Comment: If `$this->cards['name']` isn't set, this will cause an alert. Also, if it is set, it will equate to `TRUE` and not to the name.

Comment: It shouldn't, because he's explicitly checking for that.

Comment: Hi Lovau. Thanks for your answer. It fits good but sadly it does not really what I wanted. Maybe I should ask my questions more precisely :S

Comment: actually lovau, yours isn't right, since the property `$cards` holds an array within an array. so you'd need to do `isset($this->cards[0]['name']) ...` (no downvote from me tho)